# Java Regex / blank spaces issue

Tags: java, regex

```
String regex = "(\\s*T\\s*R\\s*A\\s*)*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

Trying to match "TRA", "T R A", "T   R   A", etc.  Works fine for first case, with no spaces, but not for anything with spaces (just ignores).  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

*EDIT*

Essentially, I'm trying to match all occurrences of TRA, whether or not there are an arbitrary number of spaces between each letter (or occurrence).

For example: "TRATTR A T RA T RA" has 4 occurrences, and I want to match them all with one regex.

Comment: Your example has double `T` letter after first `TRA`, is it intended?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
String regex = "(\\s*T\\s*R\\s*A\\s*)";
```

instead of:

```
String regex = "(\\s*T\\s*R\\s*A\\s*)*";
```

Your regex is trying to match 0 or more occurrences of the given text and as per your question you're just trying to match it once.

**Update:** To match multiple occurrences use code like this:

```
String regex = "(\\s*T\\s*R\\s*A\\s*)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher("T R A T R A T R A");
while (m.find())
    System.out.printf("name=[%s]%n", m.group(1));
```

Comment: Actually, I'm also trying to match "TRATRATRA", "T R A T R A T R A", and so on.  Basically, I need to match all occurrences of TRA, arbitrary number of spaces or not.  Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

For your goal, the correct regex would be `(\\s*T\\s*R\\s*A\\s*)+`, as it requires at least one occurence of TRA group and won't match out the empty string.

Example:

```
String regex = "(\\s*T\\s*R\\s*A\\s*)+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher("S T R A T R A T R A N G  E");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
} else {
    System.out.println("No match");
}
```

Output:

```
 T R A T R A T R A
```

Comment: Same result with using + (one or more).  Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @nixpunk What exactly is your code? For me, it works OK (see example)

Comment: See my bottom example for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
String regex = "(\\s*T\\s*R\\s*A\\s*)";
```